# What is this ini-file like file format?

Tags: .net, file-format

I am programming tools on top of an old system that uses a lot of configuration files in some quasi markup format. Or, possibly, this is a bastard format that once in the past branched off some genuine format. There is no header. It starts right in

```
# 
( section1
Val1 = ""
Val2 = "1"
Val3 = "1"
Val3 = "2"
Val3 = "Anchor"
)
( slave
Name = ""
Val1 = ""
Val2 = "1"
Val3 = "1"
Val7 = "0x42"
Val8 = "Default"
Val9 = 0
Val10 = 2.000000000
)
( trend_sys
# tr_sav_intv 20 1700
# tr_max_ps_len 300
# ps_trobj "IG1115" "Meas1" "PRIM" 2 1 1 1 0 300 0 0 1.000000 150 150 "" 0 0 0
# hs_trobj "IG1115" "Meas1" "PRIM" 2 1 1 0 0 40 0 0 0.000000 0 0
)
```

Another example (an actual example)

```
# storedate 21/04/10 12:07.22 (station1) station0
( Device
BlockNo = 1
BlockType = 1
)
( Device
BlockNo = 2
BlockType = 1
)
( Device
BlockNo = 3
BlockType = 1
)
```

Another version has an extra section level.

```
{ SuperSection1
( Section1 
val1 = ""
)
( Section2 
val1 = ""
)
}
{ SuperSection2
( Section1 
val1 = ""
)
( Section2 
val1 = ""
)
}
```

Note that

- section names can be identical within a file.
- value names can be identical within a section.
- values can be strings, others can be numbers (including floating point)
- lines starting with "#" are not comments. At least, they are not used only as comments. They must be preserved and accessible.

Does this format have a name? Is there any .NET support for this format?

Comment: What system is this for?

Comment: This is for a process automation system. The format is probably chosen so that it is extensible and easy to parse in the realtime system cores.

Answer (score 1):

No, this format doesn't have a name I know of and no, .NET doesn't provide native support for it. But it gives you the power to build a parser :-)